# push notification when user A sends message to user B

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Hello I have a chat app made in flutter with Firebase .

the Chat logic is already implemented and it's working fine.
I've tried using firebase cloud messaging to send notifications(from firebase console) when the app is backgrounded and it's working fine too.

What I really want to do  is to push a notification when user A sends a message to user B .(User B receives a notification)
Is there anyway to do that with only Dart code ? Or should I implement some backend code for that.
Can you tell me what is the process of the logic that I want to implement ?

Comment: There is no secure way to send messages directly from one device to another through Firebase Cloud Messaging. You will need some server-side code for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438168/sending-notification-from-firebase-to-a-specific-flutter-mobile-device and other links I provided

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for letting me know I wil take a look at the link you provided .
Should I delete this question ?

Comment: Nope, no need to delete it. In fact, Mofidul's answer seems useful (which is why I upvoted it), so consider checkng that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to implement push notifications

1. Save user B's device token in your Firebase Firestore.
   Use [Firebase Messegging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) read user device token and save to firestore user B profile(Example path db/user/token)
2. When user A sends a message to user B create a notification object and save it at db/notification
3. When user A sends a message user B triggers the cloud function to read user B's token and send a push notification to user B using that device token by firebase admin SDK

Example Cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotificationOnNewMessage = functions.firestore
  .document('db/notification/{notificationId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    // Get the notification data
    const notificationData = snapshot.data();
    
    // Get the recipient user ID (User B)
    const recipientUserId = notificationData.recipientUserId;
    
    // Fetch the recipient user's device token from Firestore
    const tokenDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('db/users/{userId}').doc("token").get();
    const recipientToken = tokenDoc.data().token;
    
    // Define the notification message
    const message = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Message',
        body: 'You have received a new message!',
      },
      token: recipientToken,
    };
    
    // Send the push notification
    try {
      const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
      console.log('Notification sent:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    }
    
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think that FCM generates a different device token every 3 days or more  (I'm not sure about this) ,the last test was before the weekend and I had to paste another registration token today in firebase console(I was using the same physical device) . However I might be wrong I just want to double check before i start implementing the logic provided above.

Comment: Edit :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982619/when-does-a-fcm-token-expire#:~:text=It%20doesn't%20expire%20though,The%20app%20deletes%20Instance%20ID
 from this post , I understood that FCM token renews itself if some conditions are triggered.
So I think I should update my collection with the refreshed token if these conditions are triggered

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Is it a good approach to update the collection everytime the token is refreshed ?

Comment: I guess yes.If you find better than this you try that as well